# jQuery.Deferred() - "new" operator is optional?

Tags: jquery, new-operator, jquery-deferred

How does jQuery implement its Deferred object so that `new` operator is optional as in `var x = $.Deferred();` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a pattern to achieve that...

```
$.Deferred = function() {
    if ( ! (this instanceof $.Deferred)) {
        return new $.Deferred;
    }
}
```

It works because `this` in a constructor is set to the new object. `instanceof` will tell you if the LHS operand has the RHS operand in its prototype chain. If this condition isn't true, the function will return an instantiated version of the object.